# render :action for polymorphic nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a polymorphic nested resource for user

```
companies/:id/users/new
departments/:id/users/new
```

Now, if the create action succeeds I can redirect to proper path (I redirect back to new) but if it fails how do I render the same page again as I need to display errors and let the filled in values as is. 'render action: new' defaults to companies/:id/users/new

```
if @user.save
   redirect_to send("new_#{@parent.class.to_s.underscore}_user_path", @parent
else
   render action: new
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, if it helps someone, it turns out in my nested form I had used @company, @user instead of @parent, @user. It should have been

```
form_for [@parent, @user] do |f|
```

Now it works fine. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try make routes through values

`redirect_to [:new, @parent, :user]`

Comment: That's a redirect, not a render. When validation fails you don't want to do a redirect, cause then you loose the user input.